# I can't make multiple labels using a for loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to have labels with "_" equal to the amount of letters in a randomly generated word, but only the last underscore shows. Am I doing something wrong? Can someone help please?

```
def play ():
    word = random.choice (list1)
    print (word)
    list2 = list (word)
    print (list2)
    x_position = 10
    for i in list2:
        lbl = Label (root, text = '_')
        lbl.place (y = 10, x = x_position)
        x_position = x_position + 5
```

Comment: What is `Label`? What library/framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using Tkinter

Comment: You set the content of the label with `text = '_'`, so that's what you see.

Comment: Please fix the indentation under your for-loop, it is clearly invalid but it's not 100% clear what your code actually looks like.

Comment: Are you saying you create, e.g., 4 Labels but only the last one is visible?

Comment: Yes I can only see the last "_", and sorry that was a mistake I made while copying my code here and it's not like that in my python file. I'll fix it asap

Answer (score 0):

```
lbl = Label (root, text = '_')
lbl.pack()
lbl.place (y = 10, x = x_position)
```